# Spring MVC xml based config to annotation

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I am new at Spring and trying to xml based config to annotation basic. I read this tutorial amd coded. It works perfect with xml based config. 
[MVC Spring CRUD Tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/3531/spring-mvc-hibernate-mysql-integration-crud-example-tutorial)

And now I converted all xml based config to annotation but I have a problem. I ried almost everything what I read but I didn't solve this problem.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void com.ulotrix.spring.controller.PersonController.setPersonService(com.ulotrix.spring.service.PersonService); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.ulotrix.spring.service.PersonService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}

**AppConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.ulotrix.spring.controller" })
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder builder = new LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource());
    builder.scanPackages("com.ulotrix.spring.model");
    builder.addProperties(getHibernationProperties());

    return builder.buildSessionFactory();
}

private Properties getHibernationProperties() {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    prop.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return prop;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public BasicDataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
    ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    ds.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deneme_db2");
    ds.setUsername("root");
    ds.setPassword("xxx");

    return ds;
}

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager txManger() {
    return new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

}
```

**SpringMVCInitializer.java**

```
public class SpringMvcInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.register(AppConfig.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

}

}
```

**PersonController.java**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {

private PersonService personService;

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "personService")
public void setPersonService(PersonService ps) {
    this.personService = ps;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listPersons(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person";
}

//For add and update person both
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person p) {

    if(p.getId() == 0) {
        this.personService.addPerson(p);
    }else {
        this.personService.updatePerson(p);
    }
    return "redirect:/persons";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}")
public String removePerson(@PathVariable("id") int id) {

    this.personService.removePerson(id);
    return "redirect:/persons";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}")
public String editPerson(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("person", this.personService.getPersonById(id));
    model.addAttribute("listPersons", this.personService.listPersons());
    return "person";
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PersonService` is defined in package `com.ulotrix.spring.services`, so change `@ComponentScan({ "com.ulotrix.spring.controller" })` to `@ComponentScan({ "com.ulotrix.spring" })` thanks to which spring can discover all the beans defined inside package `spring`.

Comment: I changed to `@ComponentScan({ "com.ulotrix.spring" })` and still same error. I am using Intellij IDEA and this is [link](http://i.imgur.com/f4OilNt.jpg) bean decleration screenshot.

Comment: Is your class `PersonServiceImpl` annotated with @Service("personService") ?

Comment: It was `@Service` annotation and I changed to `Service("personService")`. Now it works. And now receive another error. I am browse to   `http://localhost:8080/persons` and error is `SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause`

Comment: @ulotrix Glad it answers your question :) , you can create another question and paste the appropriate stacktrace.